# comparators in java collection framework

Tags: java, collections, treeset

```
    import java.util.*;
     class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{
        public int compare(String a ,String b){
            System.out.println(a+"  "+b);
            String aStr,bStr;
            aStr=a;
            bStr=b;
             int g = bStr.compareTo(aStr);
            return g;
        }
    }
    public class CompDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> ts =new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp());
        ts.add("c");
        ts.add("e");
        ts.add("b");
        ts.add("a");
        ts.add("d");
        ts.add("g");
        ts.add("f");
        for(String element:ts)
            System.out.println(element+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain how the reverse of input is happening ?
i am not able to understand how two characters are being compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not comparing characters but one-length `String`s. And your custom `Comparator<String>` returns the result of comparing the second string against the first, thus getting a reverse order. Note that the code in the comparator can be easily reduced to:

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String a ,String b) {
        /*
        System.out.println(a+"  "+b);
        String aStr,bStr;
        aStr=a;
        bStr=b;
         int g = bStr.compareTo(aStr);
        return g;
        */
        return b.compareTo(a);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [`String#compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)

---

`TreeSet<E>` uses the provided `Comparator<E>` to evaluate the order of the elements when inserting them. Let's follow the code (you should debug it):

```
ts.add("c");
//comparator will compare "c" and "c" (very silly but that's how is implemented)
//"c" will be the root of the tree
ts.add("e");
//comparator will compare "e" and "c"
//since "e" is lower than "c", "e" will be placed to the left of "c".
ts.add("b");
//comparator will compare "b" and "c"
//since "b" is greater than "c", "b" will be placed to the right of "c"
ts.add("a");
//comparator will compare "a" and "c"
//since "a" is greater than "c", "a" will be placed to the right of "c"
//but on its right is "b", so comparator will compare "a" and "b"
//since "a" is greater than "b", "a" will be placed to the right of "b"
ts.add("d");
//comparator will compare "d" and "c"
//since "d" is lower than "c", "d" will be placed to the left of "c"
//but on its left is "e", so comparator will compare "d" and "e"
//since "d" is greater than "e", "d" will be placed to the right of "e"
ts.add("g");
//comparator will compare "g" and "c"
//since "g" is lower than "c", "g" will be placed to the left of "c"
//but on its left is "e", so comparator will compare "g" and "e"
//since "g" is lower than "e", "g" will be placed to the left of "e"
ts.add("f");
//comparator will compare "f" and "c"
//since "f" is lower than "c", "f" will be placed to the left of "c"
//but on its left is "e", so comparator will compare "f" and "e"
//since "f" is lower than "e", "f" will be placed to the left of "e"
//but on its left is "g", so comparator will compare "f" and "g"
//since "f" is greater than "g", "f" will be placed to the right of "g"
//if the tree becomes unbalanced, TreeSet will be automatically balanced.
```

Comment: @saurabhkumar that's because it's showing the `String`s to be compared when adding the elements in the `TreeSet`.

Comment: System.out.println(a+"  "+b);gives me ==>c  c
e  c
b  c
a  c
a  b
d  c
d  e
g  c
g  e
f  c
f  e
f  g how these two characters are compared?

Comment: ,i understood now ,thanks for explaining briefly , you are amazing